# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

```
namespace login_page
{
    public partial class itemselect : Form
    {
        public itemselect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void product_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Addproduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-QI8RJIB;Initial Catalog=itemselect;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into itemselect([Product ID],[Product Name],[Product Quantity],[Product Price] values ('" +pid.Text+ "','" +pn.Text+ "','" +pq.Text+ "','" +pp.Text+ "')", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("item added successfully");

        }
```

Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'values'.'

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` before values which will wrap the column names in the SQL query.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 5):

Your syntax is incorrect, make sure that you have closed all your opened parenthesis.

Also, always use `SqlParameter`s to prevent [Sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and improve code readability

Sample code

```
private void Addproduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO itemselect ([Product ID],[Product Name],[Product Quantity],[Product Price]) VALUES (@ProductID, @ProductName, @ProductQuantity, @ProductPrice)";
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-QI8RJIB;Initial Catalog=itemselect;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        // Not sure about ProductID type. Could be SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier or SqlDbType.Int / BigInt
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = pid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = pp.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductQuantity", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = pq.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = pp.Text;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // Records Inserted Successfully
        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            // Error occured. Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: Please follow naming conventions when naming tables, columns and variables

Comment: Addwithvalue apparently has issues. And I don't expect quantity or price to have a text type. But yes, DO use parameters

Comment: @HansKeﬆing: implicit conversion on addwithvalue. overlooked it. hasn't been using websorms for quite sometime. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Good answer; missing a few `using`s, and honestly: I'd strongly advocate Dapper in all "running own SQL" scenarios: `con.Execute(sql, new { ProductId = pid.Text, ... });` - much less to get wrong

Comment: @MarcGravell: We use Dapper almost extensively with EF Core. Thought not to add an extra layer for the OP. Updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parathensis before the word `values`.

- Also you should use a `using` statement to ensure that the connection
  will be closed after the execution
- You should also use a `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method to avoid the
  **`SQL INJECTION`**

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...